# Can you create a Test & Target plugin programmatically?

Tags: google-analytics, adobe, ab-testing, test-and-target, snowplow

Is it possible to create a T&T plugin via the API? I've seen [people create plugins](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2012/08/how-to-integrate-adobe-test-target-sitecatalyst-google-analytics/) to pass T&T AB test data to Google Analytics and other analytics packages, and would like to do this via the T&T API because I have several clients using T&T.  I'm trying to pass T&T events to Snowplow Analytics.

Plugins require two steps - (1) HTML Offer and (2) Javascript Plugin that references the HTML Offer. It seems like you can create an HTML Offer via the API, but I don't see how to create the Javascript Plugin programmatically via the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin in Test and Target using offers. In your offer code you can get T&T values and pass them to GA or any other analytics platform.

```
var Campaign = '${campaign.name}';
var Recipe = '${campaign.recipe.name}';
```

Here is full blog post about this:

http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2012/08/how-to-integrate-adobe-test-target-sitecatalyst-google-analytics